# Why the " passwd " command give the root shell without password?

Tags: fedora, root, passwd

I have a Fedora server in which every time I execute passwd it automatically logins to root with no password necessary:

[image]

Also, passwd is unable to change root password. Furthermore, root account is enabled and have a password, I don't understand what is happening. The command `uname -r` returns : `3.8.4-102.fc17.x86_64`

Comment: Someone has broken into your server and replaced it. And with a release that old I can't say that I'm too surprised.

Comment: Then, full reinstall is probably  my best option?

Comment: Yes, nuke and reinstall. You should consider using RHEL or CentOS for a server unless you have an overwhelmingly good reason to run Fedora. And don't disable SELinux.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what's the output of `last` and `lastb`

Comment: Just read @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams comment... I would make a copy of the server image before nuking it...

Comment: @RubberStamp logins from several users. Lots of : acio  pts/1        187.222.2*** ..... lastb shows thousand of lines like : root     ssh:notty    14.99.170.195    Thu Nov 16 07:03 - 07:03  (00:00)

Comment: Also, what's do you get if you type `which passwd`?

Comment: @Roflo /usr/bin/passwd

Comment: @GAD3R passwd is /usr/bin/passwd

Comment: @roaima: I'm approximately the last person you need to warn about that, but it's all good.

Comment: @roaima: You're not wrong per se, just that I feel it's only fair to mention RHEL when I mention CentOS.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes certainly. Commercial distributions definitely have their rightful place.